# How to delete trigger in oracle that contain special character?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I don't know why in the database there are 2 triggers with name crazy 'BIN$7cCqyWWLJxbgQAEPUFlF+g==$0', 'BIN$7cK199OiZ4jgQAEPUFkgKA==$0' and try

```
DROP TRIGGER BIN$7cCqyWWLJxbgQAEPUFlF+g==$0;
```

but I can't because the name have a '+'

How Can delete these triggers?, i use oracle 10g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already dropped and in the recycle bin, which you can purge if you really need to.

Comment: @user2456216 - you can read about [the `purge` command in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9018.htm). And the recyclebin.